# jquery plugin to perform text editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a plugin in jquery as seen in image , i want to use scrollbar to achieve as shown in pic to do text editing ,
[image]

Please suggest .
Thanks,

Comment: You could use the jQuery slider plugin for the sliders: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery UI it's quite simple: http://jsbin.com/UqEbeLE/1/edit

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<textarea id="test" placeholder="Enter text"></textarea>
```

```
$(function() {
   $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value: 16,
      min: 9,
      max: 30,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#test').css({fontSize: ui.value });
      }
   });
});
```

Than for the font-family change, just populate a select box options and on jQuery change event set the new font-family value